# memset pointer + offset

Tags: c++, pointers, memset

For example, I have:

```
   DWORD pointer = 0x123456;
   DWORD offset = 0xABC;
```

I want to add `offset` to pointer and set the value at the address pointed by that pointer to `1.0f`. How do I give `memset()` a pointer and an offset as first argument?

Comment: `DWORD` isn't a pointer type, fwiw. But you would do something like `memset(reinterpret_cast<void*>(pointer + offset), ....);`. If you use an actual pointer type for `pointer` then make sure you keep pointer arithmetic in mind.

Comment: Using `memset` to assign `1.0f` is going to be a fascinating challenge.

Answer (score 1):

DWORDs are the same as uint32_t's. Just add them together as you would with any other integer.

Also, while setting a float (I am assuming you're setting a float due to the 'f' after the '1.0'), I wouldn't use memset. Just cast the pointer to a float, and de-reference it like so:

```
DWORD pointer = 0x123456;
DWORD offset = 0xABC;

pointer += offset;

float* float_pointer = reinterpret_cast<float*>(pointer);
*float_pointer = 1.0f;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be straightforward pointer arithmetic, but we've got a few preliminary issues to take care of first.

1. Why is your `pointer` variable declared as a `DWORD`?  We'll need a proper pointer type eventually.
2. Why are you asking about `memset`, if you're trying to set a floating-point value?  `memset` sets plain bit patterns; it's not much good for floating-point.
3. I assume your `offset` is supposed to be measured in bytes, not `sizeof(float)`.

Anyway, computing the pointer you want could go something like this:

```
float *fp = (float *)(pointer + offset);
```

[Notice that I perform the addition inside the parens, before the cast, so as to get a byte offset.  If I instead wrote `(float *)pointer + offset`, it'd offset by `sizeof(float).]

Once we've got that float pointer, we can set the location it points to to `1.0` in the usual way:

```
*fp = 1.0f;
```

Or we could set it to 0 using memset:

```
memset(fp, 0, sizeof(float));
```

Comment: all-bits-zero is not guaranteed to be a valid representation of `float`

Comment: @MattMcNabb: No, but I didn't say it'd set it to `0.0`, now, did I? :-) Anyway, the chances that the OP is or will ever use a machine where all-bits-0 is not 0.0 are on the order of 0.0%.

Comment: Well, it could be a trap representation. But you are right about the fact that non-IEC60559 systems are vanishingly rare.